# Missing IFC for analysis, please rebuild module with /analyze

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

Have a VS solution that builds fine except for the `Debug` profile.

When importing a c++ module from another project within the same solution I get error `C1028`:

```
C1028: missing IFC for analysis. Please rebuild module 'foo' with /analyze
```

This error seems to be new & undocumented.
What does this mean?

Comment: The EnablePREfast compiler option was set to true for the consumer project, but not for the producer project of that module. This also happens to have something to do with code analysis. I think the message should be understood as : don't mix different values of that compiler option. And then the error disappears.

Comment: And that compiler setting mismatch happened only in the Debug profile. Somehow that option was set by accident. Older msvc compilers didn't complain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project that defines and implements the module has a different value for the compiler setting `EnablePREfast` than the project that consumes the module. This causes the error.

In general it's better to have all projects in a solution share the same settings, especially if they export modules, DLLs etc.